# Is it possible to avoid changing between CSS cursor types while dragging a small element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Specifically in a case like a user dragging the handle of a slider and the cursor momentarily (due to snapping) or longer (due to off axis drag) changes from the cursor specified in the css of the handle because the mouse is no longer over the handle. I've created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sf7en4kw/) to illustrate the issue.

How can I avoid this?

---

EDIT

Stephen Thomas's answer isn't sufficient because different elements might have different icons e.g. a horizontal slider handler getting ew-resize and a vertical one getting ns-resize and I haven't seen a way to reliably determine what to 'lock' the cursor to.

---

EDIT the second

With some minor changes to Jacob Grey's answer I figured out something that serves my needs. My tweak adds a css rule that I can toggle on `<body>` to force all descendant elements to inherit its cursor. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/sf7en4kw/2/) shows the difference in behavior between Jacob Grey's solution and my tweaked solution.

```
<style> body.dragging { cursor: inherit !important; } </style>

<script>
    var disableDragCursorOverride = function() {
        $("body").removeClass("dragging");             
        $("html").css("cursor","auto")
                 .off("mouseup", disableDragCursorOverride);
    };

    $(selectorForDraggable).on("mousedown",function(e){
        var cursor = $(e.target).css("cursor");
        $("body").addClass("dragging");
        $("html").css("cursor",cursor)
                 .on("mouseup", disableDragCursorOverride);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is this example you've created?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the link now

Comment: @Bjartr is my answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very easily possible. As Stephen Thomas said, you can just add it to the `body`, but you want the cursor to be what ever you clicked on. That can be done like:

```
$('.slider').on("mousedown",function(e){
    var cursor = $(e.target).css("cursor");
    $("body").css("cursor",cursor);
});
$('body').on("mouseup",function(e){
    $("body").css("cursor","auto");
});
```

That jQuery will get the cursor for what you click on, and add it to the body, as long as the mouse is down.

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sf7en4kw/1/)

Comment: This looks like it's a good chunk of the solution, but while moving off the cursor off the handle vertically keeps the correct cursor, the cursor still flickers when it's off the handle but over the track. It appears that rules applied by other elements still override cursor rules on the body (I tried changing what you had to always append " !important" with no luck).

While I was writing this I came up with a solution, I'll add it to my question and mark this as the answer

Answer (score 4):

Not a lot of details in the question, but as a general approach:

Define a CSS rule something like:

```
.dragging {
    cursor: pointer; /* or whatever */
}
```

When dragging starts, add that class to the `<body>` or some parent container:

```
$('body').addClass('dragging');
```

When dragging ends, remove the class:

```
$('body').removeClass('dragging');
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the example link, I've added it now. This isn't sufficient because different elements might have different icons e.g. a horizontal slider handler getting `ew-resize` and a vertical one getting `ns-resize` and I haven't seen a way to reliably determine what to 'lock' the cursor to.